# Benefit of registration with Rĳksdienst Niet-Ingezetenen (RNI)

Tags: dutch-citizens

I am a Dutch citizen who has been resident in various countries outside The Netherlands since 2007.  I left the country immediately after completing my Bachelor degree and I have never paid Dutch income tax.  I am registered as a Dutch voter abroad with the Municipality of Den Haag.  I am also registered with the Ministry of Foreign Affairs via [Nederland Wereldwĳd](https://informatieservice.nederlandwereldwijd.nl/).  I recently discovered there is also a [Registratie Niet-ingezetenen (RNI)](https://www.rvig.nl/brp/rni), managed by the *Rijksdienst voor Identiteitsgegevens (RvIG)* which is part of the Ministry of *Domestic* Affairs.  Unfortunately, the RNI link to registration leads to a nonexisting page.

It is not clear to me whether I am supposed to register with RNI and whether that has any benefit.  Their website says that it is intended for *personen in het buitenland die een relatie hebben met de Nederlandse overheid*, meaning *persons abroad who have a relation with the Dutch government*.  I vote in Dutch national elections, but I can already do that.  Am I supposed to register with RNI?  Why would I?